# How do I change a folder url?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, url, directory

I have a simple question in RoR that I couldn't find a simple solution

I have a www.example.com/items folder, and I want to rename it as www.example.com/admin for every url.

Is there a way to do it in routes.rb? I tried this

this is the way I'm naming it on routes.rb:

```
Portal::Application.routes.draw do
  resources :items do
    resources :requisitos
    resources :videos
  end
```

But it didn't work.

Also, I can't just rename the folder, as there are lots of files and links that depends on it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you set the `:path` parameter:

```
match '/items' => 'items#index', :as => 'admin', :path => '/admin'
```

Keep in mind the order of precedence with routes. The line above will most-likely take precedence over the changed route of the second line for the path of `/admin`

Comment: Still didn't work. Every time I change the page the link goes back to /items

Comment: I may not understand your problem then. Are you trying to _redirect_ /items to /admin? Or are you just trying to change link anchors from /items to /admin?

Comment: I wanted to rename the url. Instead of www.example.com/items I wanted to the url to be www.example.com/admin 
For example, there are some links like www.example.com/items/post
I want to change it to www.example.com/admin/post

Comment: How are you creating to the url of `example.com/items`? Also, run `rake routes` and see what the output path is for route you want to change.

Comment: I just want the same effect as when I rename the folder /items do /admin, But I cant just rename it.

Comment: /items is a folder in app/views

Comment: Ah... I think I'm understanding it a little bit better.